# Sublime Text 2 Appending 1 column to another

Tags: append, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

Ok, so I have 2 files with a lot of data in columns that I need join. I'm finding it hard to put into words so let me try and give an example.

**File 1 contains:**

```
Server1; 15min load 0.20 at 16 CPUs;
Server2; 15min load 0.46 at 4 CPUs;
Server3; 15min load 0.10 at 16 CPUs;
...
```

**File 2 contains:**

```
72.4% (12.01)
73.9% (12.26)
72.1% (11.97)
...
```

**What I need is:**

```
Server1; 15min load 0.20 at 16 CPUs; 72.4% (12.01)
Server2; 15min load 0.46 at 4 CPUs; 73.9% (12.26)
Server3; 15min load 0.10 at 16 CPUs; 72.1% (11.97)
...
```

The dots represent thousands more lines hence the need for automation. I've tried everything that might work:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> in file 2 then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in file 1 before pasting
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in file 2 then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in file 1 before pasting

I've somehow done this before but am now struggling to replicate.

I'm aware this can be done in shell script but I'm really curious as to how Sublime text manages it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to the file2, press:

<kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> (select all, then copy)

...

Then go the the file1 and press in sequence:

<kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> 
(select all, split into lines, move cursor to the end of each line, insert a space, paste the contents.

Comment: seemly this does not work anymore... I attempted to do the exact same ting as the OP, I followed your exact steps, the result was the entirety of file2 being pasted at each line in file1 (ie: the end result was file1 line; file2 entirely CR file1 line; file2 entirely CR...

Answer (score 7):

The answer outlined by @HugoCorrá does still work in Sublime 3 on Windows 8. But you MUST make sure that the number of lines selected, matches the number of lines to paste or it does not work (it will paste a copy of the whole clipboard in each selection).

Alternatively use the [text pastry](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry) plugin for Sublime, a really nice tool for multi-line pasting. The difference being, you select the text to paste with a standard <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. Then select all the paste points in the second document (as @HugoCorrá specified), but don't do a <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>. Instead use text pastry <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + N</kbd>. Then in the command prompt use `\p` to paste from the clipboard.
An example is given [here](https://github.com/duydao/Text-Pastry/wiki/Examples).

Comment: But you MUST make sure that the number of lines selected, matches the number of lines to paste or it does not work (it will paste a copy of the whole clipboard in each selection).

Answer (score 0):

In my Sublime build 3126, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Button</kbd> to select the block B, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the block B to clipboard. <kbd>Right Button</kbd> click the right top of the block A, move mouse to the right bottom of block A to select line ends of all lines. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. The <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Button</kbd> click to select is the key step.